# What is a simple command I can run to test if I can connect to PostgreSQL using node-postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

My file db/index.js

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const pool = new Pool;

module.exports = {
    query: (text, params, callback) => {
        return pool.query(text,params,callback);
    }
};
```

In my main file main.js I do:

```
const db = require('./db/index');
```

What command can I run on db to figure out if node-postgres is able to connect to my Postgres setup correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply test if you can connect from node.js to pgsql database you can use the following snippet:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool()

pool.query('SELECT NOW()', (err, res) => {
  console.log(err, res)
  pool.end()
})

// or you can use async/await instead of callbacks
const res = await pool.query('SELECT NOW()')
console.log(res)
await pool.end()
```

This should return the response in form of pg.Result object containing current datetime.

node-postgres uses the same environment variables as libpq to connect to a PostgreSQL server, so to run the above code you can invoke it like so:

```
PGUSER=postgres PGHOST=127.0.0.1 PGPASSWORD=mysecretpassword PGDATABASE=postgres PGPORT=5432 node script.js
```

But you have to provide connection details to you database instance.

The default values for the environment variables used are:

```
PGHOST='localhost'
PGUSER=process.env.USER
PGDATABASE=process.env.USER
PGPASSWORD=null
PGPORT=5432
```

You can also provide the connection details programmatically, directly to either the `Pool` or `Client` instances. You can also use the connection string URI.

You can read more in the [node-postgres documentation](https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting) in the "connecting" section.